# Running 2 Emscripten scripts on the same page

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, emscripten

I'm making an app that uses emscripten compiled code. It first parses a file with one script while the page downloads a Unity player compiled script for HTML5.

But I would like to be able to call again the parser with another file. So I want to be able to call both of the scripts at the same time.

I call them using Module.run()

How can I avoid any conflict between the two scripts ?

Comment: I just upvoted this back to "0", but wonder why it was downvoted.  It seems like a legitimate question, and I don't recognize it as a duplicate.

Comment: Me too. Maybe my question isn't clear ?

Comment: The question seems clear to me: you want to be able to run two Emscripten programs on the same page, at once, without them clashing.  I haven't done anything like this before, BUT you might want to check out the description of web workers and how to use them: http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/api_reference/emscripten.h.html#worker-api

Comment: Hm. I have read your question two times and still it's not clear what you are asking. I can't understand your setup. Please provide more information.

Comment: I have two scripts compiled with emscripten and I need to run both of them in the same page. The problem is conflicts between the two differents Module objects generated by Emscripten. How can I do to get a parserModule and a unityModule for example, so I can call them on the same page ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emscripten output is a flat script. That means if it is in the global scope, it uses global variables.

To have multiple scripts, just put each one inside a function, so all the variables now have function local scope, and the global scope is not polluted. Something like this:

```
function moduleOne() {
  var Module = { }; // add and Module adjustments here, or leave empty
  // .. emscripten output for this module //
  return Module; // will have exported functions added to it
}

var m1 = moduleOne();
```

`Module` is necessary because if it isn't defined, emscripten will define it (globally).

Comment: Module is declared in my html ans my js file, which one of these declaration should I put in the moduleOne function ?

Comment: @Alon Zakai is there a way to tell Emscripten to wrap itself the script output inside a closure ? Is it a feature that could be in the compiler ?